# javahelp indexer for full text search

Tags: java, full-text-search, full-text-indexing, javahelp

I have a problem with the full text search database generation in javaHelp. In order to generate the db I have to execute a command from a batch file:

```
java -cp jhall.jar com.sun.java.help.search.Indexer -db .\JavaHelpSearch .\html
```

This only works if the batch file is in the same directory of the html directory containing the files to index. I have tried to execute the batch file from an external location using absolute paths:

```
java -cp jhall.jar com.sun.java.help.search.Indexer -db C:\help\JavaHelpSearch C:\help\html
```

The db generation give no erros, but if I search a word in the javaHelp window I get the following error:

```
Failed to create URL from file:/C:/help/myHelp.hs|C:/help/html/myhtml.html
```

I have spent a lot of time facing this problem, without success. What I really need is to call the Indexer class directly from my Java application, but the same problem happens there.